# Can I ignore system peer warning when connecting to AWS Keyspaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, datastax-java-driver, amazon-keyspaces

I am testing connectivity to AWS Keyspaces via sigv4 [driver](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-examples/tree/main/scala/datastax-v4/connection-sigv4) and getting below warning message

```
[info] running SampleConnectionWithSigv4 
316 [sbt-bg-threads-1] INFO com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.ContactPoints - Contact point vpce-XXXX.cassandra.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com:9142 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([vpce-XXX.cassandra.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/10.X,X.X, vpce-XXX.cassandra.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/10.X,X.X, vpce-XXX.cassandra.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/10.X,X.X])
584 [sbt-bg-threads-1] INFO com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.DefaultMavenCoordinates - DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.8.0
2766 [s0-admin-0] INFO com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.time.Clock - Using native clock for microsecond precision
4414 [s0-io-0] WARN com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.DefaultTopologyMonitor - [s0] Control node vpce-XXX.cassandra.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/10.X,X.X:9142 has an entry for itself in system.peers: this entry will be ignored. This is likely due to a misconfiguration; please verify your rpc_address configuration in cassandra.yaml on all nodes in your cluster.
4489 [s0-io-0] WARN com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.SchemaAgreementChecker - [s0] Unknown peer 7e78cfba-773a-3737-a994-2b6dd7e81775, excluding from schema agreement check
4414 [s0-io-0] WARN com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.DefaultTopologyMonitor - [s0] Control node vpce-xxx.cassandra.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/10.X.X.x:9142 has an entry for itself in system.peers: this entry will be ignored. This is likely due to a misconfiguration; please verify your rpc_address configuration in cassandra.yaml on all nodes in your cluster.
4489 [s0-io-0] WARN com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.SchemaAgreementChecker - [s0] Unknown peer 7e78cfba-773a-3737-a994-2b6dd7e81775, excluding from schema agreement check
com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.DefaultRow@299755b5
..
List of all Keyspaces in this region...
system_schema
system_schema_mcs
system
system_multiregion_info
my_test_keyspace
```